# How do I use the 'make' command to build the dagre-d3 graph library?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, npm, dagre-d3

Within a \projects directory I followed the instructions on the [dagre-d3 Github page](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3#npm-install) and typed `$ npm install dagre-d3`. Then I entered the `$ make` command as per the build instructions. Nothing happened. The error message `make: ** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.` shows. I made create a Makefile from the Github repository and when `$ make` is run the error is `make: ** No rule to make target 'browser.js', needed by 'build/dagre-d3.js'. Stop.`.

I've never used npm before but my guess is that the code author left out some file using .npmignore

Answer (score 2):

Those are two alternative methods of installation, first uses npm only whereas the second uses building from source (also needs npm), requires you to download the git repository and then run make from inside the downloaded repository root.

Comment: I finally discovered that. However, Windows throws up when running the Makefile even with GNU make and Cygwin installed. It's probably time to figure out Ubuntu or buy a mac.